# Browsers reporting Azure CDN with SSL as insecure

Tags: azure, ssl, cdn

I've obtained an SSL from Digicert according to the Azure recommendations for CDN and implemented it successfully in the Azure portal.

I'm now seeing Chrome, Edge and IE11 reporting this as an insecure domain.

They are complaining that the certificate for *.azureedge.net doesn't match the domain in the URL (assets.pipiotservices.com) - which is true!

Why is Azure CDN reporting their hostname instead of the custom hostname I have configured?

Any suggestions appreciated. This was working!!

Comment: When was it working and when did it stop working?

Comment: Do you have enabled HTTPS on custom domains?

Comment: have you binded the hostnames correctly?, if yes, attach screenshots of binding custom hostnames and certificates.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. What was the solution in your case? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, as far as I recall this was one of those mysterious Azure problems with mysteriously fixed itself after a day of errors. I've seen this many times - and suspect that Azure ops eventually fix things.